# Water not rendering

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have created a water simulation by using a domain object, an effector object and one inflow and one outflow object. When baked, the animation plays in the Blender viewport just fine. However, when clicking Render Animation, the water just doesn't show up. Here is my blend file : [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dcOnAkcGyIqR1Tj9l1XDOI8aoEp9YqLl/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't enabled *Mesh* in the domain object as you can see in the screenshot. Without it, only fluid particles are created but they are not visible in render (unless you assign objects to instance for rendering like in other particle systems). But the real water to render is usually done with the simulated mesh.

If you had set the *Cache* > *Type* to *Modular* instead of *All*, you could keep your particle simulation and simulate the mesh afterwards. With *All* you unfortunately have to simulate everything again.

[image: mesh not enabled]